# WindowConfig change when connect with bluetooth device

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth

I have some problem with connecting bluetooth device with android open source project. When I connect devices like mouse and remote via bluetooth the app activity is on or the lancher screen is duplicated although it will be removed soon but I notice the window config has changed.

I've tried with other devices that don't connect to bluetooth like a wired mouse and webcam, but it doesn't work. does anyone know the reason why, what action caused mbound to change?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, I found the solution, just declare the properties of androidconfig in the activity in manifest file, the activity will not be destroyed anymore.